# Faster ways to calculate frequencies and cast from long to wide

Tags: r, aggregate, plyr, reshape2

I am trying to obtain counts of each combination of levels of two variables, "week" and "id". I'd like the result to have "id" as rows, and "week" as columns, and the counts as the values.

Example of what I've tried so far (tried a bunch of other things, including adding a dummy variable = 1 and then `fun.aggregate = sum` over that):

```
library(plyr)
ddply(data, .(id), dcast, id ~ week, value_var = "id", 
        fun.aggregate = length, fill = 0, .parallel = TRUE)
```

However, I must be doing something wrong because this function is not finishing. Is there a better way to do this?

Input:

```
id      week
1       1
1       2
1       3
1       1
2       3
```

Output:

```
  1  2  3
1 2  1  1
2 0  0  1
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You don't need `ddply` for this.  The `dcast` from `reshape2` is sufficient:

```
dat <- data.frame(
    id = c(rep(1, 4), 2),
    week = c(1:3, 1, 3)
)

library(reshape2)
dcast(dat, id~week, fun.aggregate=length)

  id 1 2 3
1  1 2 1 1
2  2 0 0 1
```

---

**Edit :** For a base R solution (other than `table` - as posted by Joshua Uhlrich), try `xtabs`:

```
xtabs(~id+week, data=dat)

   week
id  1 2 3
  1 2 1 1
  2 0 0 1
```

Answer (score 22):

You could just use the `table` command:

```
table(data$id,data$week)

    1 2 3
  1 2 1 1
  2 0 0 1
```

If "id" and "week" are the only columns in your data frame, you can simply use:

```
table(data)
#    week
# id  1 2 3
#   1 2 1 1
#   2 0 0 1
```

Comment: +1 Blast.  You have a knack of making my solutions look totally long-winded, roundabout and pedestrian.

Comment: If you have a lot of data and operations that can't be simplified so much, then the 'data.table' package may help you.

Answer (score 11):

The reason `ddply` is taking so long is that the splitting by group is not run in parallel (only the computations on the 'splits'), therefore with a large number of groups it will be slow (and `.parallel = T`) will not help.

An approach using `data.table::dcast` (`data.table` version >= 1.9.2) should be extremely efficient in time and memory. In this case, we can rely on default argument values and simply use:

```
library(data.table) 
dcast(setDT(data), id ~ week)
# Using 'week' as value column. Use 'value.var' to override
# Aggregate function missing, defaulting to 'length'
#    id 1 2 3
# 1:  1 2 1 1
# 2:  2 0 0 1
```

Or setting the arguments explicitly:

```
dcast(setDT(data), id ~ week, value.var = "week", fun = length)
#    id 1 2 3
# 1:  1 2 1 1
# 2:  2 0 0 1
```

---

For pre-`data.table` 1.9.2 alternatives, see edits.

Answer (score 2):

A `tidyverse` option could be :

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  count(id, week) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = week, values_from = n, values_fill = list(n = 0))
  #spread(week, n, fill = 0) #In older version of tidyr

#     id   `1`   `2`   `3`
#   <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
#1     1     2     1     1
#2     2     0     0     1
```

Using only `pivot_wider` -

```
tidyr::pivot_wider(df, names_from = week, 
                   values_from = week, values_fn = length, values_fill = 0)
```

---

Or using `tabyl` from `janitor` :

```
janitor::tabyl(df, id, week)
# id 1 2 3
#  1 2 1 1
#  2 0 0 1
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(id = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), week = c(1L, 2L, 3L, 
1L, 3L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -5L))
```