# Spit column into many columns

Tags: r, split, aggregate

```
data = data.frame("id"=1:40,
                  "group"=1:5,
                  "score"=sample(1:4,10,r=T))
table(data[which(data$group==1),]$score)
WANT=data.frame("group"=1:5,
                  "score1"=c(0,4,0,4,0),
                  "score2"=c(4,0,0,4,0),
                  "score3"=c(0,4,0,4,0),
                  "score4"=c(0,0,4,4,0))
```

In data I have "score" but I want to make separate columns for each "score" and then sum up as shown here.

I also want to have my complete data frame 'WANT' and put 0s if there aren't any people but otherwise keep the same structure in terms of rows.

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186133/faster-ways-to-calculate-frequencies-and-cast-from-long-to-wide

Answer (score 0):

An option would be `spread` after getting the `count` or frequency by 'group' and 'score'

```
library(tidyverse)
data %>% 
    count(group, score) %>%
    mutate(score = str_c("score", score)) %>%
    spread(score, n, fill = 0)
```

---

If we wanted to have with the all the combinations after the `count`, use `complete`

```
data %>% 
  count(group, score) %>% 
  complete(group, score, fill = list(n = 0))
```

I also want to have my complete data frame 'WANT' and put 0s if there aren't any people but otherwise keep the same structure in terms of rows.

Comment: Thanks but this just put 1s and eliminated my count values? @akrun

Comment: @bvowe No, it is only `fill`ing 0's where there are no combinations, while the count values remain the same.  I may be getting a different output from you because there is no set.seed while creating the data

Comment: Makes sense but now suppose I want to have my complete data frame 'WANT' and put 0s if there aren't any people but otherwise keep the same structure in terms of rows, does that make sense?

Comment: I add to my comment that I combine this with the other question you answered good so if there is a better way to combine this with that response please kindly share.

Comment: @bvowe Updated the post.  But, can you please update your post with the new info as a second piece of info.

Comment: @akron one more question is if there is a way to efficiently combine this question with my one about the survey weight?

Comment: @bvowe I updated in the other post.  Also, instead of editing on the answer, can you edit on your question post

Comment: Error in count(., group, score) : object 'group' not found is an error i am getting now

Comment: @bvowe  Can you try `data %>% dplyr::count(group, score)` in case you have also loaded another package with `count`