# Creating dummy variables as counts using tidyverse/dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyverse, dummy-variable

Let's say I have some data as follows:

```
ID    FRUIT
001   apple
002   grape
001  banana
002   apple
003   apple
001   apple
```

I would like to make columns out of this, like dummy variables. Except the dummies are counts of the variable in the `FRUIT` column. So, if `ID 001` has `apple` appear 2 two times in the `FRUIT` column, the new column `apple` or `FRUIT_apple` is 2.

Expected output:

```
ID   FRUIT_apple  FRUIT_grape  FRUIT_banana
001            2            0             1
002            1            1             0
003            1            0             0
```

Not attached to these column names, whatever is easier.

Comment: `table(df)` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8186133/faster-ways-to-calculate-frequencies-and-cast-from-long-to-wide for other options.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

using `reshape2` but you could pretty much use any package that lets you  reformat from long to wide

```
    library(reshape2)
    df = dcast(fruitData,ID~FRUIT,length)
   
    > df
    ID apple banana grape
  1  1     2      1     0
  2  2     1      0     1
  3  3     1      0     0
```